# Used Google-Cloud-Vision does not return the Bangla Texts

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have connected my python program with Google-cloud-vision through API. I am getting the label_detection, Text_Detections both work and it returns only English text detections and ignore the Bangla strings/char part from the Image. In both Python and JSON output I am successfully getting English Text, but No Bangla text.  Could you please help how to solve Bangla detection part.  So that I can get both (English and Bangla Text) from the Image, for hint, same Image (Bangla+English mixed) give proper output in Google-Cloud-Vision https://cloud.google.com/vision/ page, where it says TYR THIS API.

Answer (score 0):

The result differences between the **Try this API** page and the **user API calls** are usually generated due to the properties settings that are applied during the request creation process.

I think you should try to include some additional parameters in your API calls, such as the [languageHints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages) property and the [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/features) feature type, that are used to run dense text document OCR tasks and improve the results accuracy when the service is having trouble detecting the languages used within your image. You can take a look on the [Document text detection samples](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext) and [Detecting Handwriting](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detecting_handwriting) documentation in case you want to get some code examples of the usage of these properties **(including Python code)**.

Finally, I suggest you to review [this link](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/index.html) that contains detailed information about **using Vision API with Python** that you can use as a reference to determine the service parameters configuration that better fits to your project.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I am facing problem with Bengali characters and texts

Comment: I can see that the **Bengali** language is [supported](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages) by Vision API. I suggest you try by implementing the **languageHints** property with the **bn** language code in order to verify if the text is recognized correctly. Additionally, you can take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in case you want to create a [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433) to verify this scenario with the Google Technical Support Team.

Answer (score 0):

@Ahoque: you can use the `languageHints` parameter to get your Bengali characters identified by API.

```
'imageContext': {
   'languageHints': ['bn']
}
```